# Angular : How to import a shared module in another shared module?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have created a module (SharedModule1) which contains all the Modules provided by Angular (Forms, etc) . Now i want my other Modules (SharedModules2) which are also SharedModules in nature to import this "SharedModule". And when in any Lazy loaded feature module i import "SharedModules2" it should implicitely import whatever SharedModules2 was importing (SharedModule1) .

I tried like this but failed :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LoginRoutingModule ,
    CoreModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginComponent]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

---

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CoreRoutingModule , 
    AngularModule
  ],
  declarations: [] , 
  exports : [AngularModule]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

---

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule ,
    FormsModule ,ReactiveFormsModule

  ],
  declarations: [] , 
  exports : [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule

  ]
})
export class AngularModule {

}
```

Note : LoginModule is a lazily loaded module whereas Core and Angular are not .

Comment: read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f) and then you can make a question more specific

Comment: How are sharedmodule1 and sharedmodule2 defined and where are they used?

Comment: The Module definitions i provided in the description is the way i am trying to use . And as *Note says LoginModule is laziliy loaded whereas others are not